# Apache Name Based Virtual hosting unable to view websites

Tags: apache, virtualhost, centos7

I am trying to setup Name Based Virtual Hosting centOS7 minimal install

My `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` is configured like this :

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName original.com
    ServerAlias www.original.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/original
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testa.com
    ServerAlias www.testa.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testa
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testb.com
    ServerAlias www.testb.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testb
</VirtualHost>
```

My `/etc/hosts` is configured like this :

```
`192.168.5.15 testa.com
192.168.5.15 testb.com
192.168.5.15 original.com`
```

My `/var/www` containts :

```
ls -R /var/www/   

/var/www/:
cgi-bin  original  testa  testb

/var/www/cgi-bin:

/var/www/original:
index.html

/var/www/testa:
index.html

/var/www/testb:
index.html
```

At this point I am trying to open the pages in chrome and firefox but It just opens the original websites testa.com testb.com original.com.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks :(

Comment: thanks Vipin, I managed to locate the problem with ping and fix it ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the result of `ping testa.com` and `"grep ^hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf"`  from your PC ?

Comment: Thanks ! The problem was me, everything actually worked fine but since I have my server inside a virtual box I was trying to access the pages from my main PC and not inside the virtual box. When I ping testa.com from within the virtualbox it gives me the correct address, but when I ping it from my PC it doesnt.